# If a class has a public List of a custom class, how do I know when List Item # (record number) I am using?

Tags: c#, progress-bar

I am trying to create a progress bar class like below.  If the child time remaining is greater than the parent time remaining then the parents should equal the childs time remaining.

In method CalcETA() below I am having difficulty accessing the child's properties.  I thought if I know what List Item # I am on I could somehow access the ProgressBarList[myIndex+1] values...

```
public class ProgressBars
//NOTE: Not working yet
// used to keep track of multiple progress bars and the time remaining.
// recommended to set as default: Min = 1, Max = 100, Step = 1, Value = 1 in progress bar property control.
{
  public List<ProgressBarItem> ProgressBarList;

  public bool Started { get; set; }       // set to true if you want to keep track of when to update bars on form.
  public string Status { get; set; }      // general text

  public class ProgressBarItem
  {
    public bool HasChild { get; set; }     // if HasChild = True then parent TimeRemaining must not be less than childs.
    public int Maximum { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan TimeRemaining { get { return CalcETA(HasChild, StartTime, Value, Maximum); } }
    public TimeSpan ElapsedTime { get { return DateTime.Now - StartTime; } }
  }

  private static TimeSpan CalcETA(bool HasChild, DateTime StartTime, int counter, int counterGoal)
  {  // Calculate the time remaining for the process
    if (HasChild)  
    {
      //TODO: How do I get the child's StartTime?
      TimeSpan timeElapsed = DateTime.Now - StartTime;
      return GetETAFromTimeElapsed(timeElapsed, counter, counterGoal);
    }
    else
    {
      TimeSpan timeElapsed = DateTime.Now - StartTime;
      return GetETAFromTimeElapsed(timeElapsed, counter, counterGoal);
    }
  }


  private static TimeSpan GetETAFromTimeElapsed(TimeSpan ts, int Counter, int CounterMax)
  {
    if (Counter != 0)  // do not divide by zero
    {
      double minLeft = (ts.TotalMinutes / Counter) * (CounterMax - Counter);
      return TimeSpan.FromMinutes(minLeft);
    }
    else
      return default(TimeSpan);
  }
```

**UPDATE 1:**

Note Question should read: If a class contains a List of a custom classes, how do I get the class List Item # when working in a list item get property?

Sounds like I need to look up Nested Classes, thanks for the term.
Maybe this is clearer:
Problem: A child progress bar has time remaining (ETA) of 5 minutes.  Parent progress bar has ETA of 2 minutes which is misleading.  Therefore set parent progress bar to 5 minutes also.

1. Every progress bar is a class in a list.  i.e. `List<MyProgressBar>`
2. Every progress bar needs to calculate ETA.
3. When calculating ETA for any progress bar check if it has a child progress bar and if current ETA < child ETA use the child's ETA.
4. I am assuming that every item added in list is a child of the above. (maybe bad assumption)
5. Since every progress bar is an item in a list how:
   a) Can I get the current list index number inside the class methods?  i.e. List[num].
   b) Can I access other list item values (like child startime) ? i.e. List[childnum].

Thoughts:
1. As I was taking a break I though that I could override the List.Add() method to insert the item #?  But then I have to maintain this value.

Comment: Ok but how are making the parent-child relation in your scheme? How do you know which ProgressBarItem is the child of another one?

Comment: It may be worth taking a look at the [Microsoft Naming Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzf533w0%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), there is some inconsistency in the code, which is a pet hate of mine.

Comment: Perhaps I need to rework my assumption that progress bars added are the child of the last item added.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little confused by your code

In answer to your title question though, to find the index of the ProgressBarItem within the list you can use the IndexOf() method, depending on where the CalcETA code ends up being run you will either want to pass it the List, in which case you'd use IndexOf(this) or you pass it the ListItem in which case you'd use IndexOf(listItem)

I hope this is of some help for your original question, that code as it stands needs significant reworking though.

Comment: Nested classes are standard C#, although much more at home in Java. More often than not I'd advise a code file per type, however if the type grouping is appropriate, like the example then it seems reasonable to me.

Comment: that wasn't the only bit that confused me, but looking back I may have misread part of it.
There is still nothing to indicate which progressbar you are trying to find the children of.

Comment: Please see my Update 1 above in question text.

Answer (score 0):

Add a properties with **ProgressBarItem type(Parent)** that store parent of per ProgressBarItem, Then to find childs of a Node:

```
var Childs=ProgressBarList.Where(p=>p.Parent==Node);
```